# How do I run pianobar (pandora) from a shell script with config access

Tags: python, shell

I can run pianobar from command by typing pianobar and it loads the config file just fine. I want to run it from a python script or shell script and it runs  but it does not load the config file. Pianobar is a PATH that you can run from any directory and I don't know where the app is installed. I'm working on a GUI for Raspberry pi.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you share what did you try so far? Please also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So far I tried from a python script os.system("pianobar"), and subprocess.call("pianobar", shell=True). And from the shell pianobar --/home.pi/.config/pianobar/config and also just pianobar. My config file is set to user root. The config file has the password needed for pandora and also other parameters. I also tried putting the INIT INFO at the top of the shell script. Next I will try to run it at boot and see if it  works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, to run it from a shell do: **sudo -u pi pianobar**